# Word Interop Issue with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, office-interop

About Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.

I installed the PIA and Microsoft Office 2010 in my web server, but I can't generate a .doc when I run the application published in my web server. When I run my application in localhost, works fine, and generate the .doc file.

I have to do some configuration in server side to allow the generation of .doc files ?

Comment: Do you see any exception in server logs?

Comment: The print spooler failed to reopen an existing printer connection because it could not read the configuration information from the registry key ...1005\Printers\Connections. The print spooler could not open the registry key. This can occur if the registry key is corrupt or missing, or if the registry recently became unavailable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that Office 2010 was not designed to run inside a web server (e.g., thread safety might not be guaranteed), so you might encounter more difficulties down the line.

Instead, consider using the [Open SDK 2.0 from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx), which allows you to manipulate (create, edit) Office 2010 documents, which are simply packaged (zipped) XML files. This technology is much better suited for server use. It also doesn't require you to have a separate Office 2010 license for each web server where you are going to install Office 2010.

Comment: I agree with you, but I need a quick solution while I implement another solution like that.

Comment: @Lucas_Santos, quick solution doesn't work. It is simply wrong to use Office Interop in a server application. It's not what it was designed for.

Comment: @Lucas_Santos, spend the time upfront, rather than later when you have to track down and fix issues on your production server caused by the inappropriate use of the Office DLLs on a server.

Comment: ok, but, i'm working in a inherited projct, and the another company implement this solution that I told. It's wrong, I agree with everybody. But to implement another solution, I need more time, and then I need a solution for Interop, while I implement a new solution like Open Sdk like you said

Comment: @Lucas_Santos, there is no solution with Office Interop. Office Interop doesn't work in server applications such as ASP.NET. It is as simple as that. So the *architect* that took the decision to use Office Interop in a server application should probably pay the extra time that you will have to spend to fix his errors.

Comment: Understood. Thanks a lot everybody, so my only option is develop a Open SDK instead of Interop.Word.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the Open XML SDK for this. The office interops are outdated relics, and should not be used.

Download link:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124

Here's a simple example of how to create a Word document:

```
public void HelloWorld(string docName) 
{
  // Create a Wordprocessing document. 
  using (WordprocessingDocument package = WordprocessingDocument.Create(docName, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document)) 
  {
    // Add a new main document part. 
    package.AddMainDocumentPart(); 

    // Create the Document DOM. 
    package.MainDocumentPart.Document = 
      new Document( 
        new Body( 
          new Paragraph( 
            new Run( 
              new Text("Hello World!"))))); 

    // Save changes to the main document part. 
    package.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save(); 
  } 
}
```

See this MSDN article for more details:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd440953%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Comment: This will be the future of my application. I need a time to implement that. So, to this moment, while I didn't finish the Open SDK development, I need a solution for Interop.Word

Comment: It's most likely a compatibility issue, and you'll probably have to compile your application to run in 32-bit mode.

Answer (score 0):

Office Interop is NOT supported by MS in "server-like scenarios" (which IIS/ASP.NET is a special kind of)... see http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757#kb2

Your options include several libtraries (free and commercial) - for example:

- [MS OpenXML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124) (free)
- [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx) (commercial)

Regarding the exception you get:

Since Windows Vista several changes have been introduced to stop any Windows Service (IIS is just some special one) from doing anything "desktop-like" - this is due to security issues... to resolve such a situation you would need to circumvent those security measures implemented by MS - which I absolutely do NOT recommend...